# $\mathbb{1}\uparrow_H^{G}$ is the permutation representation on $G/H$

Tags: representation-theory

Is the following correct?

If we have $G$ is a group with $H\leq G$ and we take $\mathbb{1}$ to be the trivial character on $H$ then I am trying to show that $\mathbb{1}\uparrow_H^{G}$ is then the permutation character on $K[G/H]$.

So in order to define the induction we pick coset representative $g_i$ with $g_1=1$ so that we have a partition of $G$ into $\{g_1H,\ldots ,g_nH\}$. Now if we suppose that $V$ was the vector space associated with the trivial representation of $H$ then we define a new vector space $W=\oplus g_iV$.

We then define the action of $G$ on $W$ by writing uniquely $g.g_i=g_j.h$ for $h\in H$.

Then for $g\in G$ and $g_iv\in W$ we have $g.(g_iv)=g_j\rho(h)(v)$ for $\rho$ the rep of $H$ on $V$.

Now as our $\rho$ is the trivia representation then the we simple get $g.g_iv)=g_jv$ and so we are just permuting the space. Is this all I need to say?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Looks alright to me.

Comment: "trivia" -> "trivial", and H should probably be finite index in G. Texo: put braces around the uparrow, $\mathbb{1}{\uparrow^G_H}$. Unbalanced paren in second to last paragraph.